# Некорректное автодополнение к импортам в библиотеке (конфигурация package.json)

Tags: typescript, npm, импорт, vue3, package.json

Вопрос по npm конфигу. Пытаюсь из проекта сделать библиотеку.  Получаю некорректные подсказки к импортам в автокомплите IDE после установки библиотеки в проект.
А именно:

```
import {} from 'table/dist';
```

Такой импорт не работает, но автокомплит предлагает его почему-то.
Правильный импорт. который работает, выглядит так:

```
import {} from 'table';
```

Но его я могу использовать только с @ts-ignore и потеряв типизацию.
Конфиг package.json выглядит так:

```
 {
  "name": "table",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build-cli": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue --name table --mode production ./src/index.ts",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "precommit": "npm run build"
  },
  "main": "./dist/table.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/table.es.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/table.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/table.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
  "unpkg": "dist/table.umd.min.js",
  "types": "src/types/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "src",
    "dist"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.18.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.19",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.30.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3",
    "vite": "^2.5.10",
    "vue": "^3.2.19"
  }
}
```

vue.config.js

```
/**
 * declaration (.d.ts) files.
 * Discussed here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1081
 */
const fixEmitDeclarationFilesForTypeScript = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      config.module.rule("ts").uses.delete("cache-loader");
      config.module
        .rule("ts")
        .use("ts-loader")
        .loader("ts-loader")
        .tap((options) => ({
          ...options,
          transpileOnly: false,
          happyPackMode: false,
        }));
    }
  },
  parallel: false,
};

module.exports = {
  ...fixEmitDeclarationFilesForTypeScript,
  filenameHashing: false,
  runtimeCompiler: true,
```

};

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
const path = require("path");

const resolvePath = (str: string) => path.resolve(__dirname, str);

export default defineConfig({
  alias: [
    {
      find: "@",
      replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  ],
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      name: "table",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
      plugins: [
        typescript({
          target: "es2017",
          rootDir: resolvePath("./src"),
          declaration: true,
          declarationDir: resolvePath("./dist"),
          exclude: resolvePath("./node_modules/**"),
          allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Проект на vue 3 + ts, собирается через vite. Библиотеку устанавливаю в другой проект через команду `npm install git_url`.
Проект собирается в папку dist. В файле ./dist/table.umd.js находятся все импорты.
Куда копать?

Comment: Сперва капнуть [сюда и попытаться оформить это в виде exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_approach_2_isolate_state).

Comment: капнул, пришлось добавить использование vite, пока та же проблема.. вопрос обновил